# Kafka user authentication using SASL_PLAINTEXT

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to implement security in Kafka to authenticate the clients using username and password. The jaas config file is configured properly. I'm starting zookeeper first and then starting just one kafka node. However kafka fails to start with the below error:

```
[2017-08-07 13:07:08,029] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: EndPoint(localhost,9092,ListenerName(SASL_PLAINTEXT),SASL_PLAINTEXT) (kafka.utils.ZkUtils) 
[2017-08-07 13:07:08,035] INFO Kafka version : 0.11.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) [2017-08-07 13:07:08,036] INFO Kafka commitId : cb8625948210849f (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser) 
[2017-08-07 13:07:08,037] INFO [Kafka Server 0], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)    
[2017-08-07 13:07:08,447] WARN Connection to node 0 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) 
[2017-08-07 13:07:08,554] WARN Connection to node 0 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) 
[2017-08-07 13:07:08,662] WARN Connection to node 0 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: The error message "Connection to node 0 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials. " keeps getting printed continuously. Dunno how auth comes into play when just starting one kafka node.

Comment: How do you start the broker?

Comment: @vahid I'm using the command "EXTRA_ARGS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=../config/kafka_server.jaas ./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties" . Turns out i was missing the zookeeper jaas config file. I've got it working for now, any idea if this approach is feasible for authorization for different users?

Comment: Hi, can you able to resolve this issue.